# Summing values that match across two arrays

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet setup as follows:

[image]

My goal is to create a matrix of the reference column and in that matrix, I want to show the sum of the values where the ID is present in both references. For example, in this data table, the ID's "A" and "E" are present in reference 1 and reference 2 (see orange highlights). Hence, in the matrix output, at the intersection of reference 1 and 2, I would want to show the sum of the values of ID's A and E. The actual dataset is larger.

Can anyone help with an Excel formula that would allow this.

Currently I am using lookups to identify the ranges of the references (i.e. the range of cells for reference 1 and the range of cells for reference 2). My plan was to then try to sum_duplicates(ref_1_range, ref_2_range) if such a formula existed.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the difference between the cell at (1,2) and (2,1)? Wouldn't they both show the sum of values that occur in both references?

Comment: Have you tried using a Pivot Table?  You can add the ID column to the Rows section and the Value (Sum) to the Values section.  That will show the sum of all values for each ID.  You could also add the Ref column to the Values section and change to Count to see where there are counts>1.

Comment: There is no difference between (1,2) and (2,1), I just need one half of the matrix :) unfortunately a pivot table won’t quite solve it as I need to see how the summer value of the overlaps between references (i.e where the sum of the ID values where the ID values are the same in 2 references

Answer (score 1):

You could use a helper column that checks whether that value is in the other reference, then sum on whether that column `= TRUE`

**For example:**

[image: helpercolumn]

- The formula in `D2` is: `=COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,A:A,"<>"&A2)>0`
- The formula in `G2` is: `=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,F2)`
- The formula in `H2` & `G3` is: `=SUMIFS(C:C,D:D,TRUE)`
- The formula in `H3` is: `=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,F3)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it - this is one approach, for H2 looking up pairs like 1A,1E,1E,1D,1E,1A,1G in the first two columns combined (1A,1B,1E,1D,2E,2A,2G) then narrowing down the matches to the ones with a reference of 2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$C$8*ISNUMBER(MATCH($F2&$B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8&$B$2:$B$8,0))*($A$2:$A$8=H$1))
```

[image]

I have filled in the other elements of the 2 X 2 table as a check, and changed C4 to 3 to make the four totals different.

**EDIT**

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$C$8*(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,$F2,$B$2:$B$8,$B$2:$B$8)>0)*($A$2:$A$8=H$1))
```

is a bit better.